# Is there any way to convert IntPtr / void* to ref SomeStruct in C#?

Tags: c#, pointers, ref

Subj. The use case is: let's assume I have an unmanaged buffer that stores N instances of `SomeStruct`. So having an address in this buffer, is there any way to convert this address to `ref SomeStruct` -- e.g. to be able to update these structs directly?

P.S. I am aware of upcoming `Span<T>` type. I am curious if there is any way to do something similar in C# right now.

Comment: Yes, via unsafe code and Marshalling, but it's not something I do often enough to give you more than that.

Comment: can you do it in c/c++? is the address from another process or same process?

Comment: Are you looking for [Marshal.PtrToStructure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ca6d5z7(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: In an `unsafe` context and assuming the structure contains no references, you can cast the pointer to the buffer's first element to `SomeStruct*` (pointer arithmetic is supported to access other elements) and can access the fields through C#'s [-> operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/operators/dereference-operator) like you would in C or C++.  This will modify the memory directly (albeit in an unsafe manner).

Comment: Marshal.PtrToStructure copies the data. I want to get a "ref" to the data instead.

Comment: I refer to "ref returns / ref parameters" C# feature here.

Comment: @PeterHuene yes, it's similar to this -- the only problem is that you can't return such a pointer. But C# supports ref params and ref returns, so I asked if there is any way to convert such a pointer to ref in C#.

Comment: @AlexYakunin afaik, C# does not support casting unsafe pointers to `ref`, so if you're constrained by using a `ref` parameter or return then, to the best of my knowledge, the answer to your question is "not yet". Personally, I'd be surprised if they do allow it in the future as it would effectively erase the unsafe nature of the access.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, found the answer: `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.AsRef<T>` solves the problem. More on this: http://adamsitnik.com/ref-returns-and-ref-locals/

Comment: It probably has to be blittable too.

Comment: It would be nice if the CLR could have some concept of mapping it to an array (aka C pointer, but typesafe, but I guess `Span` is the answer).

Comment: Yes, `Span<T>` is the answer, but it is not there yet :) I was looking for doing somewhat similar, but without `Span<T>`, and it looks like that's the way to do that: you can get a pointer to an array element in unsafe code, so that's how to convert it to a safe ref return.

Comment: Is there an equivalent of "Unsafe.AsRef<T>(IntPtr value)" that doesn't require casting IntPtr into a T* pointer?